# How to assign the address to boost::shared_ptr in c++?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have got:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Car> sptr;
```

Now I would like to assign an address from other object:

```
Car object;
sptr = &object;//error
```

As we can see in the comment there is an error. So my question is how can I assign an address from some object to shared_ptr? 
If it was normal a pointer the case would be simply:

```
Car *ptr;
Car object;
ptr = &object;//ok
```

How to use in this case boost::shared_ptr? Thanks

Comment: If `boost` works anything like the `std`, you want to use `&(sptr.get())`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466459/create-a-boostshared-ptr-to-an-existing-variable

Comment: *"As we can see in the comment there is an error."* Yes, there is an error, however, you didn't add the _actual error message_. Always copy those, as they might contain helpful information. In this case Dietmar's answer contains everything important, but your next question might be a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

You *could* make the assignment work by explicitly converting your pointer to a `boost::shared_ptr<Car>`:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Car> sptr;
Car object;
sptr = boost::shared_ptr<Car>(&object);
```

However, that would be an extremely Bad Idea:

1. When the last copy of `sptr` goes out of scope, `Car` would be `delete`d but it was never `new`ed. Although you might be able to work around this problem by using a suitable deleter, i.e., one which doesn't do anything, this doesn't really help:
2. Since `object` lives on the stack, it is destroyed when it goes out of scope, not when the last copy of `sptr` goes out of scope.

You should only manage objects on the heap with shared pointers. Stack allocated objects and objects embedded into other objects have their own life-time management.

Comment: I noticed that both your and Linuxios answer use `= boost::shared_ptr<...>()`. Is there any particular reason for not using `shared_ptr<...>::reset(Y * ptr)`, apart from personal taste?

Comment: @Zeta: `reset()` would work, too. Constructing the `boost::shared_ptr<...>()` would give the opportunity to also pass a deleter. However, it is essentially personal taste.

Answer (score 0):

A raw pointer, e.g. `Car*`, can point to another object, wherever it may be.  It can be on the stack, or on the heap, it doesn't matter.  The raw pointer does not 'own' the object -- ie. it will not clean up the object -- it simply says "the object is over there".

A smart pointer, e.g. `shared_ptr<Car>`, tries to 'own' or 'manage' the object.  The object must be allocated on the heap, and probably allocated with `new`.  When the shared_ptr goes out of scope, it cleans up the Car by `delete`ing it.  Thus, a shared_ptr must only hold a heap-allocated object.

I.e.:

```
Car foo;  // stack allocated
Car* p = &foo;   // points to the stack-allocated Car foo.
shared_ptr<Car> sp (new Car);  // heap-allocates a Car, and holds it in a smart ptr.
p = sp.get();  // p points to the heap-allocated Car held by sp.
shared_ptr<Car> sp2 (&foo);  // BAD.  it will compile, and die at runtime.
```

Side note:

shared_ptr allows multiple shared_ptrs to point to the same object, and won't clean it up until all of the shared_ptrs are gone.

The bad shared_ptr usage will die when it goes out of scope and tries to delete the stack-allocated Car.  This can give you misleading stack traces, and be difficult to debug.