# Cast 'this' to std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have a method on a class to make a particular instance an "active" instance:

```
void makeActive() { activeInstance = this; }
```

However it doesn't work since `activeInstance` has type `std::shared_ptr< ClassName >`. How can I cast `this` to `std::shared_ptr<ClassName>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a boost::shared\_ptr to an existing variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466459/create-a-boostshared-ptr-to-an-existing-variable)

Comment: This uses `std::shared_ptr`, so some semantics might differ.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your object **is already owned** by a `shared_ptr`, you can produce another `shared_ptr` by having your object inherit from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

This code will then work:

```
void makeActive() { activeInstance = shared_from_this(); }
```

If your object **is not already owned** by a `shared_ptr`, then you sure as heck don't want to create one in `makeActive()` since a `shared_ptr` will try to delete your object when the last one is destroyed.

Comment: You can still create a shared_ptr if your object is not already maintained by one.  See my answer.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I totally agree... you can see that I was careful not to say that it *can't be done*.

Comment: You said "a shared_ptr will try to delete your object when the last one is destroyed" but this is not true if you use a null deleter as I explain in my answer.  Saying "you sure as heck don't want to create one" is too strong a statement, because it is possible to do it safely.

Comment: @JohnZwinck +1 to your answer.  I can't be comfortable with adding the "null deleter" proposition as *safe code*, but please keep your answer up as well.

Answer (score 3):

This will "work" (but see below):

```
activeInstance.reset(this);
```

The problem is, what does it *mean*?  When `activeInstance` goes out of scope, `this` will be `delete`d.  That may not be what you want.  You should also read about [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/enable_shared_from_this/), which would allow you to say:

```
activeInstance = shared_from_this();
```

Another option is to use a "null deleter", that is, specify a deleter function which does nothing:

```
void NoDelete(void*) {}

activeInstance.reset(this, NoDelete);
```

In many cases this will be a safe and correct solution, assuming that `this` will be deleted by some other method elsewhere, and not before the last dereference of `activeInstance`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `activeInstance` is either a global or static class member, and thus won't go out of scope.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: well then it will be destroyed on program exit, which may still lead to a double-delete, therefore undefined behavior.

Comment: Or use the aliasing constructor instead of a null deleter: `activeInstance = std::shared_ptr<ClassName>(std::shared_ptr<ClassName>(), this);`

Comment: T.C.'s suggestion has the advantage that the shared_ptr won't allocate a control block internally.  The disadvantage, though, is that you can't use weak_ptrs.